# Warn command in discord.py doesn't work and doesn't send any error message, and after a minute the bot gets offline

Tags: python, discord.py

So basically whenever I run the .warn command it crashes the bot without returning any error message and doesn't write anything in both of the json files.

I had previous errors related to me not awaiting some functions but I fixed them, I'd like to fix this error as soon as possible.

I have not included the imports and the os path in the code.

Please do not resell the code you find below:

```
async def openinf():
    with open("infractions.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    return users
# made by boredscripter (aleissues on stack)
async def openuseless():
    with open("caseids.json", "r") as f:
        caseids = json.load(f)
    return caseids

async def addcaseidtodb(caseid):
    e = openuseless()
    
    e[str(caseid)] = {}

    with open("caseids.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(e, f)
    return True

async def id_generator(size=12, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
    while True:
        x = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
        existing = await openuseless()

        for caseid in existing:
            if not caseid == x:
                return x

async def createinfraction(user, type, mod, date):
    users = await openinf()

    idgen1 = await id_generator()
# boredscripter

    users[str(user.id)] = {}
    users[str(user.id)]["type"] = type
    users[str(user.id)]["mod"] = mod.id
    users[str(user.id)]["date"] = date
    users[str(user.id)]["caseid"] = idgen1


    with open("infractions.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
    return True

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("online")

@client.command(aliases = ["w"])
async def warn(ctx, member : discord.Member = None, *, reason = None):
    if member is None:
        embed = discord.Embed(title = "ERROR", description = "Please specify a valid member.")
        await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention, embed = embed)
    elif reason is None:
        embed = discord.Embed(title = "ERROR", description = "Please specify a reason.")
        await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention, embed = embed)
    else:
        yui = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
        await createinfraction(member, "Warning", ctx.author, yui)
        embed = discord.Embed(description= f"You have been warned in {ctx.guild} for {reason}.")
        await member.send(embed = embed)
        e = client.get_channel(loggingchannel)
        embed1 = discord.Embed(title = "Member Kicked", description = f"{member} has been kicked")
        embed1.add_field(name = "Reason", value = reason)
        embed1.add_field(name = "Moderator", value = ctx.author)
        x = await openinf()
        for user in x:
            if user == member.id:
                if x[str(member.id)]["date"] == yui:
                    embed1.add_field(name = "Case ID", value = x[str(member.id)]["caseid"])
        embed1.add_field(name = "Date", value = yui)
        await e.send(embed=embed1)
```

Comment: Please, reduce your code to a minimum reproducible example. Nobody will read all that code.

Comment: `now` variable is undefined.

Comment: Gonna need some more information of what you tried. Your `warn` command when working properly, will send two embeds. I am going to assume no embeds were sent. Also what happens when you don't enter a `member` or `reason`, are the error embeds still sent? If they are, then your issue is most likely within the `createinfraction` function.

Comment: @Ratery they said the whole code wasn't posted so hopefully they defined it previously since that would have raised an error

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO thats all i can reduce as its full of useful functions which build up my code.

Comment: @Ratery it is defined, just not there and it would have raised an error if it wasnt there

Comment: @Roopesh-J just attempted to do warn without any argument, the embed was sent so there's an issue inside the createinfraction function but i dont get where

Comment: And no embeds are sent even with correct arguments? If so, I would make specifically test the `createinfraction` function. You can print `users` and `idgen1` to make sure those two data objects are okay. Also I recommend just commenting out lines in your `warn` command that you know will work for sure. Essentially try to isolate the issue as much as possible. Because right now we don't even know where the issue is and it's hard for me to reproduce your error because of the nature of it.

Comment: module may run it in separated thread which may block displayed text - or it may have function which catch all error so server may run even with errors. You may need to send own information to file or use module `logging` - so you could later see all messages in file.

Comment: @Roopesh-J wdym embeds arent sent with the correct arguments?

Comment: Sorry, if meant to ask if no embeds are sent even when `warn` is called with the correct arguments

Comment: embeds are sent, it fails to log it on the json file @Roopesh-J

Comment: Oh if embeds are sent than the issue could be anywhere. I recommend really just testing the individual functions and then debugging the `warn` command by stopping at certain points and see what the json files/dictionaries look like. You can just `print` them out or something

Comment: i changed ID system, and it worked so it's the ID system which doesnt like json